# Find all possible abelian groups of order $120$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Find all possible abelian groups of order $120$.

If someone could walk me through how to do this, that would be great.

Comment: [This](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_24) may help. Also, [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely-generated_abelian_group).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Start by taking $120$ and decomposing it into its prime factorization.

$$120 = 2^3\times 3 \times 5$$

Then apply the [Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely-generated_abelian_group):

Essentially, the Theorem, as it applies to finite abelian groups, says that every *finite* abelian group $G$ is isomorphic to a direct sum of primary cyclic groups. A primary cyclic group is one whose order is a power of a prime. That is, every finitely generated abelian group is isomorphic to a group of the form
$$\mathbb{Z}_{p_1} \times \mathbb Z_{p_2} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}_{p_t},$$
where the numbers $p_1,...,p_t$ are primes or powers of (not necessarily distinct) prime numbers.

Also, you'll find it helpful to use the fact that $$\mathbb Z_{mn} \cong \mathbb Z_m\times \mathbb Z_n \iff \gcd(m, n) = 1$$

This can be generalized to any number of $n$ factors : $$\mathbb Z_{\large m_1m_2\cdots m_n} \cong \mathbb Z_{\large m_1}\times \mathbb Z_{\large m_2} \times \cdots \times \mathbb Z_{\large m_n}\;\text{ if and only if the }\, m_i \,\text{ are pairwise prime.}$$

---

Putting the above together, we should find that there are exactly three non-isomorphic abelian groups:

$$\mathbb Z_{120} = \mathbb Z_2 \cong \mathbb Z_{2^3}\times \mathbb Z_3 \times \mathbb Z_5$$
$$\mathbb Z_{2}\times \mathbb Z_{60}\cong \mathbb Z_2 \times (\mathbb Z_{2^2} \times \mathbb Z_3 \times \mathbb Z_5)$$
$$\mathbb Z_{2}\times \mathbb Z_{2}\times \mathbb Z_{30} \cong \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2 \times (\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_3\times \mathbb Z_5)$$

Answer (score 4):

Use the fundamental theorem of abelian groups.  If you have not seen it, try to follow the proof.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, we have the following cases,since $$120=2^3\times 3\times 5$$

$$2\times 2\times 2\times 3\times 5\\ 2\times 2\times 6\times 5\\2\times 60$$ Note that using the point that @amWhy indicated is essential here. In fact, $(2,3)=1$ and $(12,5)=1$. Below is the codes in GAP which we can see what is happening for abelian group of order $120$:

```
gap> e:=AllGroups(120, IsAbelian, true);;
     for i in [1..Size(e)] do Print(StructureDescription(e[i]),"\n"); od;
C120
C60 x C2
C30 x C2 x C2
```